# CUDA Parallel NSight Debugging host and device simultaneously

Tags: cuda, nsight

Does anyone know if its possible to Debug CUDA using parallel NSight on a remote machine? I am able to step into CUDA code but not my host code. It says CUDA has the capability to generate host debug information so debugging remotely and locally should be possible.
My card is a 580 GTX.

```
//device code <-- able to debug device code
//host code   <---- when device code returns, should be able to debug host code
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simultaneous GPU/CPU debugging from a single IDE instance is unfortunately not possible with the current releases of Nsight and Visual Studio.

As a workaround, you can start GPU debugging from one copy of Visual Studio, then open a second IDE instance and attach its CPU debugger. They won't have unified stepping, but you can at least set breakpoints independently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I remember doing simultaneous debugging way back. Perhaps it was when there was deviceemu. I thought it was still available

Answer (score 0):

It should now be possible to attach both the Visual Studio default debugger and NSight in the same VS instance. Then this should work.