# How to set breakpoints both in Host and Device code

Tags: cuda

I'm new to CUDA.
I want to set breakpoints both in host code (C++) and device kernel code (CUDA code), but i only succeed to stop for debugging on host **code OR device** code(but **not on both** of them together.

I'm using VS2010 (win7) with Cuda 4.2 and Nsight 2.2.
What do i do wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps you should identify what debugger you are using, as well as your OS.  The answer to your question will vary based on those responses.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I edited my question according to your recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to simultaneously debug device and host code with Nsight VSE 2.2

Please refer to the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686119/cuda-parallel-nsight-debugging-host-and-device-simultaneously).  This question is a duplicate of that one.

As an additional reference, refer to the first note on this nsight VSE [documentation page](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Launch_CUDA_Debugger.htm).